# Automatic backup of MySQL data in linux

Tags: mysql, linux, backup

I've been searching for an easy script to backup MySQL data in Linux automatically (weekly basis) but couldn't find something clear to me. I am doing the back up manually:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword billing  -r "/file/private/billing_backup.sql
```

Can you please guide me to an easy script that perform the automatic backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can throw the command you provided yourself in a script, and add that to cron. See http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html for instructions on how to do that.

This'll overwrite /file/private/billing_backup.sql every time; you can use timestamped filenames to avoid that

Answer (score 3):

The attached bash script is what I use that runs in cron daily. The bash script will email you notification when the backup has completed. the backups are kept for 5 day and then removed after that. I also have this script send me notification on the server information such as memory and storage of my backup directory. Please feel free to modify this script to work with your needs. You will want to change some of the variables in the # variables section of the bash script.

The section for the email in the script will also need to be modify to use your email address in the NOTIFY_EMAIL="root@gmail.com".

You can add the mysql root user account information in my.cnf in the root directory or within the bash script under the # [ Define Variables ].

you will need to chmod the bash script with

```
$sudo chmod +x backupmysql.sh
```

This will allow you to run the script manually with the following command or use the crontab listed below to automate the MySQL backups.

```
$sudo ./backupmysql.sh
```

You can name the script whatever you like. In this example, I named it nightly_mysql_backup.sh.

Here is the nightly_mysql_backup.sh bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
############################################################################
#
# Script:   nightly_mysql_backup.sh
# Date:     05-23-2018
# Author:   
#
# Description:  
#
# Usage:        
#
# History:  
#
############################################################################
#
# Variables
HOST=`hostname -s`
DELETE_BACKUPS_OLDER_THAN_DAYS=5
syslogtag=MySQL-Backup
DEST=/var/dba/backup/
DBS="$(mysql -u root -Bse 'show databases' | egrep -v '^Database$|hold$' | grep -v 'performance_schema\|information_schema')"
DATE=$(date +'%F')
MIN_BACKUP=1000 #NOTE: 1 Kilobit = 1000 bit
DAYS_KEPT=5

# Backup all existing databases.  Currently disabled, can be enabled to backup certain individual databases.
#DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
#DBS="$(mysql -u root -Bse 'show databases' | egrep -v '^Database$|hold$' | grep -v 'performance_schema\|information_schema')"
# Or specify which databases to backup
#DBS="mysql zarafa"

# DO NOT BACKUP these databases.  Currently disabled, can be enabled to not backup certain individual databases.
#NOBKDB="test"

# Send Result EMail can be toggled on or off
SEND_EMAIL=1
NOTIFY_EMAIL="root@gmail.com"
NOTIFY_SUBJECT="MariaDB Backup Notification on ${HOST}"

# Linux bin paths, change this if it can't be auto detected via which command
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GREP="$(which grep)"
CHOWN="$(which chown)"
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
MAIL="$(which mail)"
FIND="$(which find)"
DF="$(which df)"
FREE="$(which free)"
DU="$(which du)"

# Function for generating Email
function gen_email {
DO_SEND=$1
TMP_FILE=$2
NEW_LINE=$3
LINE=$4
if [ $DO_SEND -eq 1 ]; then
if [ $NEW_LINE -eq 1 ]; then
echo "$LINE" >> $TMP_FILE
else
echo -n "$LINE" >> $TMP_FILE
fi
fi
}

# Temp Message file used for recording data on backup and cleanup
TMP_MSG_FILE="/tmp/$RANDOM.msg"
if [ $SEND_EMAIL -eq 1 -a -f "$TMP_MSG_FILE" ]; then 
rm -f "$TMP_MSG_FILE"
fi

set -o pipefail

# Start backing up databases and check if today's backup already exists
STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
for db in ${DBS[@]};
do  

skipdb=-1
if  [ "$NOBKDB" != "" ];
then
for i in $NOBKDB
do
[ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
done
fi

GZ_FILENAME=$HOST-$db-$DATE.sql.gz

if [[ -f ${DEST}${GZ_FILENAME} ]]; then 
echo "Backup file ${DEST}$GZ_FILENAME already exists for today. Exiting."
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "Error: Backup files ${DEST}$GZ_FILENAME: already exists for today."
elif  [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then
# connect to mysql using mysqldump for select mysql database
# and pipe it out to gz file in backup dir
mysqldump -u root --quote-names --opt --single-transaction --quick $db | gzip -cf > $DEST$HOST-$db-$DATE.sql.gz
ERR=$?
if [ $ERR != 0 ]; then
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Error: $ERR, while backing up database: $db"
logger -i -t ${syslogtag} "MySQL Database Backup FAILED; Database: $db"
else
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Successfully backed up database: $db "
logger -i -t ${syslogtag} "MySQL Database Backup Successful; Database: $db"
fi
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"
echo $NOTIFY_MESSAGE
fi
done

ENDTIME=$(date +%s)
DIFFTIME=$(( $ENDTIME - $STARTTIME ))
DUMPTIME="$(($DIFFTIME / 60)) minutes and $(($DIFFTIME % 60)) seconds."

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

# Log Time
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "mysqldump took: ${DUMPTIME}"
echo "mysqldump took: ${DUMPTIME}"

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

#Make sure we have a minimum number of files.  If we don't than e-mail.
DATABASE_COUNT=$(mysql -u root -e 'show databases;' | egrep -v '^Database$|hold$' | grep -v 'performance_schema\|information_schema'| wc -l)
BACKUP_COUNT=$(find ${DEST} -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.gz' | wc -l)
if [ $BACKUP_COUNT -eq 0 ] 
then
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="No backup files exist in $DEST. total files: $BACKUP_COUNT  ERROR!!!!"
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"
echo $NOTIFY_MESSAGE
elif  [ $BACKUP_COUNT -le  $((($DATABASE_COUNT) * ${DAYS_KEPT})) ]
then
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Only found $BACKUP_COUNT backup files. No cleanup will be done at this time.";
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"
echo $NOTIFY_MESSAGE
elif [ $BACKUP_COUNT -gt $((($DATABASE_COUNT) * ${DAYS_KEPT})) ]
then
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="$BACKUP_COUNT backup files over the amount. Cleanup to occur on $DEST"
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"
echo $NOTIFY_MESSAGE
fi

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

#Delete backups older than 5 days
total_backup=$(ls -tr $DEST | wc -l)
TO_DELETE=$(find ${DEST} -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.sql.gz" -daystart -mtime +    $(($DELETE_BACKUPS_OLDER_THAN_DAYS-1)) -print | sort | head -n $total_backup)
if [ -n "$TO_DELETE" ]
then
echo "Deleting the following files: $TO_DELETE"
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Deleting the following files: $TO_DELETE "
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "Deleting: $TO_DELETE: "
echo $TO_DELETE | xargs rm
echo "Files deleted."
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="OK: Files deleted."
else
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="No files to delete."
fi

gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"
echo "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE"


# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

for i in ${DEST}*.sql.gz
do
#Check to make sure we have a backup from today. If we don't then e-mail
if [[ ! -f ${DEST}/${GZ_FILENAME} ]]; then 
echo "Today's backup file, ${DEST}/${GZ_FILENAME}, not found.";
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Today's backup file, ${DEST}/${GZ_FILENAME}, not found.";
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE" 
fi

#Make sure the backups has some reasonable size to it. If it doesn't then e-mail
SIZE_BYTES=$(stat -c%s ${i} )
SIZE=$(( SIZE_BYTES + 512 / 1024 ))
if [[ ! $SIZE -gt $MIN_BACKUP ]]; then
echo "Backup file: ${i} is smaller than the expected size.  Expecting > ${MIN_BACKUP} bit and got ${SIZE} bit";
NOTIFY_MESSAGE="Backup file: ${i} is smaller than the expected size.  Expecting > ${MIN_BACKUP} bit and got ${SIZE} bit";
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "$NOTIFY_MESSAGE" 
fi
done

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

# Disk space stats of backup file system
if [ $SEND_EMAIL -eq 1 ]; then
$DF -h "$DEST" >> "$TMP_MSG_FILE"  
fi
$DF -h "$DEST"

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

# Memory stats of file system
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "Memory status on $HOST: "
echo "Memory status on $HOST: "
if [ $SEND_EMAIL -eq 1 ]; then
$FREE -m -h >> "$TMP_MSG_FILE"  
fi
$FREE -m -h

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

# List of current backup files email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 "List of current backup files: "
echo "List of current backup files: "
if [ $SEND_EMAIL -eq 1 ]; then
$DU -hsc --time --apparent-size ${DEST}* >> "$TMP_MSG_FILE"
fi
$DU -hsc --time --apparent-size ${DEST}*

# Empty line in email and stdout
gen_email $SEND_EMAIL $TMP_MSG_FILE 1 ""
echo ""

# Sending notification email and cleanup of temporary file
if [ $SEND_EMAIL -eq 1 ]; then
$MAIL -s "$NOTIFY_SUBJECT" "$NOTIFY_EMAIL" < "$TMP_MSG_FILE"
rm -f "$TMP_MSG_FILE"
fi

exit
```

Set the crontab job to the following using crontab -e.  This will run every Sunday at Midnight.
$sudo crontab -e

```
0 0 * * 0 /path to backup file/nightly_mysql_backup.sh
```

You can use gunzip to uncompress the sql.gz file.

Answer (score 1):

[automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) is a fairly good tool for maintaining backups of mysql databases. Not sure if it can be directed to only do weekly backups, but it will rotate backups on weekly and monthly basis.